# LAM app earning is Halal.or Haram?

Tags: money

There is an app called LAM which offers its users to earn online by watching youtube videos. But first you have to invest some money according to available packages for example, 4000, 15000 and so on.You have to watch 4 or 10 videos daily and per video price is 40 or 50 and you will earn 4800 on 4000's package and 18000 on 15000's package Monthly.

Answer (score 2):

This app was a scam and is not available anymore. They have exploited millions of rupees and fled.
https://tribune.com.pk/story/2446655/ponzi-earning-app-lam-disappears

Answer (score 0):

From your description I feel like it is some type of scam or why you should pay them for getting paid to watch video. Knowingly falling into any trap can be wrong.

> Spend in the cause of Allah and **do not let your own hands throw you
> into destruction** ˹by withholding˺. And do good, for Allah certainly
> loves the good-doers. [Quran 2:195](https://quran.com/en/al-baqarah/195)

Usually what happens in these type of sites is, you will pay first, then you will start earning some money and they will have set amount after which you can withdraw. But when you get near to that amount they will suspend your account, so in effect you will pay initially and never get back anything from them.

This is my personal view, you can do your own research before making a final decision.

Comment: Jazak' Allah for the response but my cousins are getting their payment every month, just guide me should i start or not. Is it halal if i earn through this?